# randomly select 2 columns from multidimensional array -list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array-list

```
test_list =[[1,2,3,4,5],
          [6,7,8,9,10],
          [11,12,13,14,15],
          [16,17,18,19,20]]
```

So I want to print out all possible array when I randomly select 2 columns,for example,I can choose column 1 and 2, also I can choose column 2 and 4, or ...

```
a = [[1,2],
     [6,7],
     [11,12],
     [16,17]]

b =[[2,4],
    [7,9],
    [12,14],
    [17,19]]
```

I can use `my_list = [[row[0], row[1]] for row in test_list]` to select 2 assigned columns. But I am not sure how to randomly select 2 columns and print out all possible output.

Comment: Are you trying to select two columns randomly, or list all possible combinations of two columns?  Either way, you probably want to transpose the matrix so that you're selecting rows rather than columns, then transpose your selection. If you have to do stuff like this a lot in your code, you might want to consider using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes,try to list all possible combination of two column results

Comment: If you want random columns, use the `random` package.  If you want all combinations, use `itertools`.  Documentation is available on line with a simple search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all the combinations of a certain size.

```
from itertools import combinations

def transpose(mat):
    return list(zip(*mat))

test_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]

pairs = (transpose(x) for x in combinations(transpose(test_list), 2))

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)
```

gives us

```
[(1, 2), (6, 7)]
[(1, 3), (6, 8)]
[(1, 4), (6, 9)]
[(1, 5), (6, 0)]
[(2, 3), (7, 8)]
[(2, 4), (7, 9)]
[(2, 5), (7, 0)]
[(3, 4), (8, 9)]
[(3, 5), (8, 0)]
[(4, 5), (9, 0)]
```